# auto-pst-pdf or pdftricks2?

Tags: pstricks, best-practices

When I compile a LaTeX documents containing PSTricks code, I normally use the package [`auto-pst-pdf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/auto-pst-pdf), but recently I found [`pdftricks2`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdftricks2).

Should I use `auto-pst-pdf` or `pdftricks2` and what are the differences between the two packages?

P.S. Shouldn't I use one of the packages above at all when compiling documents containing PSTricks code via PDFLaTeX, but a third one? If so, which one?

Comment: use `xelatex` and you do not need any additional package. However, there is not _the_ package when using `pdflatex`, choose the one which you may prefer.

Comment: @Herbert Okay. Do you know what the package differences are? (If you put your comment(s) into an answer, I'll accept it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Program `xelatex`: does the conversion of the whole document in the background with `xdvipdfmx`
- Program `pst2pdf` (Perl) extracts all `pspicture` and `postscript` environments and creates single standalone documents to run with `latex' to create a graphic for each document which is then used instead of the environment.
- Package `auto-pst-pdf` loads internally `pst-pdf` and runs the document with the `pspicture` or `postscript` environments in the background with `latex` and then uses the created pdf images instead of the environments in the `pdflatex` run
- Package `pdftricks2` can convert only `pspicture` environments and needs a special handling of the PSTricks packages in the preamble. It also replaces the `pspicture` environment with the created image.
- Package `pdftricks` works similiar to `pdftricks2`

Comment: And the `powerdot` presentation package works with neither of them.

Comment: why should it?? It is per definition created for `latex` and _not_ `pdflatex`!

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Using `standalone` document class compiled with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` produces better cropping than using `pdfcrop`-based workflows. (It is based on my own experiences) Don't trust me without involving your own fingers to prove what I am saying. :-)

Comment: @ClickMe: `standalone` itself also use `ps2pdf`!t

Comment: @Herbert: `ps2pdf` or `pdfcrop`?

Comment: @Herbert You're right, but as there was talk around TeX.SX that it may work with XeLaTeX, and the non-`pdflatex` compatible stuff is AFAIK all PostScript/PSTricks-based, I hoped that there would be a solution. Not really a problem, just worth mentioning.

Comment: @Herbert: I don't understand why you emphasized that `standalone` also uses `ps2pdf`? Is it not a typo? Or you want to say `standalone` also uses `pdfcrop`? Oh my ghost. I got confused.